# How to get lunar L, B, C parameters from the Moon's 3x3 rotation matrix from the Python package Skyfield?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, the-moon, mathematics, python, skyfield

Answers to [What are the “Moon L, B, C” angles shown in this solar eclipse simulation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22375/12102) explain that L and B (or "l" and "b") are the "selenographic coordinates of the Moon's apparent center" (latitude and longitude respectively) as seen from Earth. While those two define the sub-Earth point, C is then used to determine the angle that the Moon's axis is rotated around that line it defines relative to Earth's axis in some way.

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/42122/12102) to *Ephemeris for lunar body-centered body-fixed coordinates?* describes [two Python methods in the Skyfield package](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/planetary.html#computing-lunar-libration) that provide either the latitude and longitude parameters (L, B) or a 3x3 rotation matrix.

**Question:** How can one use those results to then calculate the L, B, C parameters? I'm assuming that the 3x3 rotation matrix contains what's needed but I'm not sure how to do the conversion.

[image: lunar L, B, C parameters from NASA Goddard video Tracing the 2017 Solar Eclipse]

**above:** Screen shot from [NASA Goddard video Tracing the 2017 Solar Eclipse](https://youtu.be/MJgXaqW3md8), **below:** screen shot from [Taylor et al. 2011](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/publications/reports/Tayloretal2011.pdf) (also NAO Technical Note No. 74 2010 August, [Computation of the Quantities Describing the Lunar Librations in The Astronomical Almanac](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a528116.pdf)) borrowed from [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/27357/12102).

[image: lunar L, B, C parameters]

> Figure 1: The selenocentric sphere: showing the lunar orbit and the relationships between the subEarth point M, the mean lunar equator and the ecliptic. S is the descending node of the lunar equator on the ecliptic.

Comment: Have you considered opening an [issue](https://github.com/skyfielders/python-skyfield/issues) - as the functionality is either not present or insufficiently documented. (the package appears to know it, as it can point to a specific lunar lat/lon)

Comment: @JCRM Here I've asked how these existing methods can be used to *generate* L, B and C.. I'm sure there's a transform that can take the 3x3 and do that, but I don't know what that would be. If nobody answers I may try it myself.