# Does Perseverance have a gnomon on it?

Tags: mars, the-sun, time, perseverance, sunlight

Though [How many sundials, Sun compasses and gnomons are there on solar system bodies?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32348/12102) is as yet unanswered, Wikipedia's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MarsDial currently tells us that only the following three are on Mars:

- MER-A Spirit
- MER-B Opportunity
- MSL Curiosity

Insight has a gnomon of sorts as shown in the linked question (on the seismometer shroud), but perhaps it's not a proper *MarsDial*.

**Questions:**

1. Does Perseverance have a gnomon on it?
2. If so, is it of the MarsDial variety?
3. If so, is it the same as Curiosity's, or has it been upgraded/modified?

---

[image: MarsDial on Spirit (cropped, zoomed, sharpened)]

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:MarsDial_and_Rock_Spirit.png) (cropped, zoomed, sharpened)

> A true-color image of the MarsDial taken by the Spirit rover. Created using images taken in filters L2, L3, L4, L5, L6 & L7. Images were interpolated into the XYZ colorspace using a spline interpolation of order 3 and then transformed into the sBGR colorspace.
>
> - Date: 29 July 2014, 18:12:48
> - Source: NASA/JPL/Cornell University

---

That's gnomon, not *[gnome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnome)!*

[image: gnomes] [Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Gartenzwerg.jpg)

Comment: For those Makers amongst us,  https://web.archive.org/web/20150518103822/http://sundials.org/attachments/article/68/MakeYourMarsDial_NyeLabs.PDF

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It was shown and described in the [NASA press conference at about minute 31](https://youtu.be/gYQwuYZbA6o?t=1864):

[image]

And here is a close up of the Gnomon from the [latest press conference](https://youtu.be/bdlfdBiSzKw?t=1039) showing much more detail:

[image]

Comment: Hmm simultaneous post as uhoh's edit... Sorry

Answer (score 4):

Yes, according to [mastcamz.asu.edu](https://mastcamz.asu.edu/mars-in-full-color/) .  The text there calls it a 'calibration target' but makes it clear that it's a Marsdial chock-full of inscriptions as with Curiosity's Marsdial.

Comment: Sorry to edit ad then roll back, it seems I'd duplicated the other answer at the same time it was posted.

Comment: @uhoh   NP;  I appreciate the work in any case