# Is pinging the Moon with a laser as shown on "The Big Bang Theory" possible?

Tags: the-moon, reference-request, experiment, laser, optical

In an episode of season 3 of *The Big Bang Theory*, the cast sends a laser pulse to the Moon. This seems to be a real thing: [What Neil & Buzz left on the Moon](https://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2004/21jul_llr/) (2004). My questions are:

1. Could somebody explain how to reproduce this test?
2. What should the power of the laser be?
3. How can one find the reflector on the Moon?

Some links or recommendations are very welcome.

Comment: What's 'pingin'?

Comment: "Pinging" (sp).  As in "To ping the moon."

Comment: You can also [bounce radio waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth–Moon–Earth_communication) off the moon, which is a bit easier actually.

Comment: Note that not only do you need access to a telescope beyond anything I've heard of in amateur hands but you need FAA permission to do this and they're probably not going to grant it for casual curiosity.  (The issue is ensuring the outgoing pulse does not meet up with a pilot's eye.  It would do permanent damage.)

Comment: @LorenPechtel It's a serious topic, but *unlike a laser pointer*, the beam diameter is usually huge (a meter or so) and the human pupil a half-dozen millimeters. So "It would do permanent damage" is questionable. Risks from satellite and lunar ranging experiments as well as next generation optical communications with spacecraft are more likely distraction or confusion of the pilot.

Comment: @uhoh it's only questionable if your total power is comparable to that of a laser pointer. But to do lunar ranging you need quite a bit more power, so that power density would be considerably higher.

Comment: @Ruslan no, it's still questionable in that case as well. It's a factor of a million or more in area, but probably only between 100 and a 1,000 in power (estimating tens of mW versus < 10 Watts). So the amount of power that goes through a 6mm hole is much smaller.

Comment: Previously asked on other sites: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82276/amateur-moon-laser-ranging , https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/24686/is-this-laser-experiment-shown-on-big-bang-theory-possible .

Answer (score 65):

There is a very nice Myth Busters video about bouncing a laser off the Moon linked below.

To answer your question, current work is done with an array of corner cube reflectors on the Moon roughly 50 x 50 cm in size. Pulsed lasers on Earth have traditionally been green [frequency-doubled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_optics#Frequency_doubling) infrared [Nd:YAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nd:YAG_laser) lasers, similar to the "classic" [DPSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode-pumped_solid-state_laser) green laser pointers before they commercialized green diode lasers. That's why older green laser pointers were so expensive, heavy and large, they contained a semiconductor diode laser, and an infrared Nd:YAG crystal laser, and a frequency doubling crystal all on a tiny "optical bench" inside the pointer.

Don't be put off by the "peaks at 1 giga Watt" mentioned in the video, that's the *instantaneous* power during the very short, probably a few nanosecond pulse. The average power of the laser is going to be a few Watts or so. That's why each pulse contains "200 quadrillion photons".

The laser beam has to be collimated with a large telescope (like a meter or more in diameter) to make the spot on the moon small enough, and the received photons on Earth has to be collected with a large telescope as well. Each pulse usually results in only a few photons actually detected by a photomultiplier tube. You run for a while and collect enough photon statistics to average out the noise and get a precise time measurement. A special, very narrow pass optical filter is used to make sure light of other wavelengths on say the brightly lit lunar surface don't make it to the photomultiplier tube, or else it would just saturate.

You can read further about the retroreflectors in these Stack Exchange questions and answers as well:

Space SE:

- [What are these structures on the Lunar Ranging Retro Reflector (LRRR) arrays for?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14943/12102) some images
- [Local expansion measured, near zero via Lunar Ranging - what about deep space probes?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14921/12102) cool images
- [Who does these mesmerizing simulations of the phases of the Moon? And how?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19936/12102)  cool GIFs!

Physics SE:

- [Is the metric expansion of space relatively uniform on different length scales?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/251088/83380)
- [How is a result of no time variation in the gravitational constant G related to a measurement of no local expansion?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/251700/83380)
- [Would order 1AU metric expansion of space begin if the solar system were not inside a galaxy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/268353/83380)

Answer (score 36):

The University of Texas's McDonald Observatory performs laser measurements of the distance to the Moon using retroreflectors left by the Apollo astronauts.

You can read all about it in the McDonald Laser Ranging [page](http://www.csr.utexas.edu/mlrs/).

[image]

Lots of technical details in this [paper](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/LRRR-94-0193.pdf).

Comment: Wow! Thank you! Very good link! Especially: https://ilrs.cddis.eosdis.nasa.gov/network/stations/active/MDOL_sitelog.html#5.%20%20%20Laser%20System%20Information

Comment: Thanks! I just added a link to a technical paper with a lot of details.

Comment: It is not only the University of Texas's McDonald Observatory doing laser measurements of the distance to the Moon. There are several observatories doing this, see this [list](https://ilrs.cddis.eosdis.nasa.gov/network/stations/index.html).

Comment: I did not say it was exclusive.

Comment: @OrganicMarble neither Uwe implied that you did nor that your answer was incomplete or anything :)

Answer (score 2):

Even though the question has already been mostly answered, here is more information about current Lunar Ranging activities.

The *EUROLAS Data Center (EDC)* of the *Deutsches Geodätisches Forschungsinstitut* at *Technische Universität München* has a nice website with an API to find laser ranging data. The data are the same than on the CDDIS website as the data are mirrored in several research organisations for redundancy reasons.

The typical data structures for laser ranging are:

- Normal Point and Full Rate Data in CRD files: contains the delay between signal transmission and bounce reception by the ground station
- Predictions in CPF files: contains the predicted target position in International Terrestrial Reference Frame (ITRF), so that the ground stations can point their lasers accurately at the target.

You can find data for the 5 Lunar Ranging targets here:

- [Apollo 11](https://edc.dgfi.tum.de/en/satellites/apollo11/)
- [Apollo 14](https://edc.dgfi.tum.de/en/satellites/apollo14/)
- [Apollo 15](https://edc.dgfi.tum.de/en/satellites/apollo15/)
- [Luna 17](https://edc.dgfi.tum.de/en/satellites/luna17/)
- [Luna 21](https://edc.dgfi.tum.de/en/satellites/luna21/)

As you can see, the lunar targets are still actively used, in average once a month, sometimes more often, sometimes less often.