# Is there any spacecraft that is ping-able?

Tags: communication, internet

I was wondering if there are any spacecraft that is ping-able, not necessarily straight through the internet? It would be a fascinating test to run "ping url/ip" and see the response time to space.

Or, that there is some dashboard or site that shows the response time to a satellite.

I tried to search here and on search engines but got no relevant answers.

Comment: Not an answer since you cannot do it yourself, but https://eyes.nasa.gov/dsn/dsn.html has live round trip times.

Comment: There are [OSCARs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_radio_satellite), radio amateurs communication satellites.

Comment: There are services you can pay for, and there are emergency signals you can send like this: [Which satellites can hear emergency signals from Scott Kelley's watch?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30763/12102) and there's [How does the Satellite Networked Open Ground Station operate? How is it used?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24471/12102) and [these also](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24469/12102) but I don't think these are exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: satellite phones or pagers come to mind

Comment: As you can access to internet though satelittes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_Internet_access) and most routers (perhaps including those in those satellites) are ping-able, you may be able to ping such a satellite. I don't have such an access, otherwise I would have test and post the result of my tests as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer, is yes, there are spacecraft you can "ping" (or do a non TCP/IP equivalent).

For two-way communications, implied by your desire to "ping" you should look at the [amateur radio satellites](https://www.amsat.org/).  Many of these serve as packet repeaters.  You need to be a licensed amateur radio operator, and have the right equipment, or course.  A two-way UHF/VHF amateur station probably runs you in the \$5k to \$10k range.  Of course, not all amateur satellites use UHF or VHF.  For the ultimate satellite "ping" using an amateur radio station you can also [bounce a signal off the moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%E2%80%93Moon%E2%80%93Earth_communication).

One of the best known amateur satellites is [AO-7](https://www.amsat.org/two-way-satellites/ao-7/).  Satellite became non-operational in 1981 due to a battery failure, and then in 2002 came back to live as the battery went from a short to an open circuit.  When active in sunlight (since it has no batteries) it has two repeater modes that are available to the public.

If a two-way station sounds too complicated, there are plenty of satellites that you can listen to with a simpler downlink-only station.  [SatNOGS](https://satnogs.org/) is a particularly popular open-source network of ground stations, and their web site has great tutorials for getting started.  You can even download images from US government weather satellites.  This [tutorial](http://mattg.co.uk/words/noaa_sdr/) shows how it can be done with a software define radio and hand held antennas (investment < \$200)

Comment: But the questioner wrote : " It would be a fascinating test to run "ping url/ip" So he asked for a ping over the internet using an url and an ip.

Comment: AR stackexchange might disagree with your quote of a couple of thousand: https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/16565/equipment-pricing is talking about hundreds, not thousand.

Comment: @user1937198 - Apples and Oranges.  That thread is for some basic gear to get started in the Ham hobby.  Not for two-way satellite communications.  A good multi-band radio for satellite can run you north of $1000, although SDRs are bringing prices down.  Antennas, rotors, preamps, LNAs, etc will quickly add up.

Comment: @Carlos N depends on your definition of satallite, and communications. It explicitly mentions pinging the ISS as something that is unreliable but possible with basic gear.

Answer (score 5):

Some space satellites can be pinged with a laser. These satellites are equipped with laser corner reflectors(Proba-V (EKA), Sentinel-3 etc):

[image]

Several satellites are laser reflectors:

[image: Etalon]

[image: Larets]

[image: BLITS-M]

To ping a satellite you need a laser and a telescope.
[image]

Comment: I love it!!! :-)

Comment: A good telescope mounting is needed to aim the laser at the reflecting sat and to track it over some time.

Comment: Some satellites ping you:  https://www.facebook.com/astroalert/posts/2638586623025375

Comment: speaking of retroreflectors on satellites: [Are there any possible proxies for dust accumulation on the retroreflectors on the moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46154/12102)

Comment: @A.Rumlin oh that is so cool! So I've just asked [How many (presumably friendly) lasers are being shot at us from space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46159/12102)

Comment: @uhoh Another illustration of CALIPSO https://www.facebook.com/astroalert/posts/2802205206663515

Comment: @A.Rumlin I'm not hooked up to social media and FB seems to want me to upload my hard drive  before it will let me see that page ;-) https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgWZE.png

Comment: @uhoh copy https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0r1k.jpg

Comment: ah, that's beautiful! :-) (more retroreflector sightings: [1](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23538/12102), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32677/12102), [3](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27945/12102))

Answer (score 2):

**That's no spacecraft... it's a Moon!**

Mirrors left on the Moon can measurably reflect lasers shone at it here from Earth, showing the response time to space, specifically to the Moon.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Laser_Ranging_experiment

[Is pinging the Moon with a laser as shown on "The Big Bang Theory" possible?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/30138/is-pinging-the-moon-with-a-laser-as-shown-on-the-big-bang-theory-possible)

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82276/amateur-moon-laser-ranging

Not really an answer to the question as asked, but might scratch the same itch.

Comment: Ha! I'll follow in Sheldon's footsteps :-)

Comment: speaking of retroreflectors on the Moon: [Are there any possible proxies for dust accumulation on the retroreflectors on the moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46154/12102)